# Select specific value out of a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, time, posixct

I want to select a specific value from a data frame and can't figure out how. Here's the data frame:

[picture of data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBi6L.png)

I want to select a specific value from the column "X1", but I don't want to access it through the index (1 to 10), but by using the "time"-column.

If I wanted to select the value X1 from row 8 (0.89) through the index, I could do this:

```
df[8,"X1"]
```

But I want to access the value through the Date & Time. I didn't find a solution yet. The time-column is basically the column X and X.1 merged into one separate column with a POSIXct format (%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S).

Something like this (but doesn't work like that):

```
df[df$time[2018-08-10 13:29:20], "X1"]
```

I would be thankful for any ideas.

Comment: Hi, I think it is very easy. Try the following: `df[df$time == "2018-08-10 13:29:20", "X1"]`

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately, I receive an error: Error: unexpected '=' in "x <- df[df$time ="

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very easy. 
You have just to do a comparision like

```
 df[df$time == "2018-08-10 13:29:20", "X1"]
```

if you want to have all values of "X1" greater than a specific time you can even go with lager or lower comparisions like

```
 df[df$time > "2018-08-10 13:29:20", "X1"]    
 df[df$time >= "2018-08-10 13:29:20", "X1"]    
 df[df$time < "2018-08-10 13:29:20", "X1"]    
 df[df$time <= "2018-08-10 13:29:20", "X1"]
```

The comparision will create a logic vector which gives you all rows back where the logic vector is `TRUE`

If it is not working properly you have to be shure your time-comlumn is in the right format like POSIXct. You can do it with `as.POSIXct`

Comment: Tank you very much, that worked :) The == did the trick. But now I get a Vector wit a "NA" as a result: 
[1] 0.89    NA  
But I only want the 0.89 value... I think I can figure that out

Comment: @JanStamm you can use the function isTrue() for this issue. Please have a look at this Link. It might be usefull: 
https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-tip-use-istrue/